# Does correcting the link in question count as trivial change?

Tags: discussion

Mostly new users on SO seem to have problem adding hyperlinks feature provided by SO to their question. So I have been correcting them as according to standard SO format. But other than that most questions seem to need no actual editing. So my question is does editing just the links count as trivial change (which SO asks not to bother making changes to) or we can proceed to do so?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're doing this in active questions only. There is nothing wrong with those edits if there really isn't anything else to fix. Many existing meta questions about rejected edits however prove that many people think too lightly of the subject of what can and needs to be edited so maybe you want to explore that a bit more.

Comment: they are active ones yes.

Comment: Note that there are two ways to create a link: using `[link text](url)` or `[link text][1] 1: url`. Please do not edit posts to change one to the other. I've seen that happen, and it's annoying, since both formats work fine.

Comment: i have been doing it only on the ones that directly post the links itslef

Comment: If you are in-lining images then that is fine.